# ¿Cómo leer un float con scanf en C?

Tags: c, float

¿Cómo se puede hacer para que la variable float cambie al valor que desea el usuario y esta permanezca así?

```
void paso(void);
float globalpaso = 65;
int operacion;
int main(void)
{
  do
    {
  printf ("===> OPERACIONES DE GESTIÓN\n");
  printf ("1) Distancia de un paso\n");
  scanf ("%d", &operacion);

  switch (operacion){
case 1:
    printf("El valor actual del paso es de\n");
    printf("Introduzca el nuevo valor para la medición del paso\n");
    paso();
  break;
default:
  break;
    }   
  }
  while (operacion != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de nada, si tu función no recibe ningún parámetro no hace falta le pongas void, con que la declaración vacía es suficiente `void main(){`.

Para cambiar el valor de la variable `globalpaso` con el input del usuario, deberías hacer lo mismo que haces con operación pero especificando el formato como float

```
scanf("%f", &globalpaso);
```

El código entero quedaría así:

```
float globalpaso = 65;
int operacion;

int main()
{
  do
    {
  printf ("===> OPERACIONES DE GESTIÓN\n");
  printf ("1) Distancia de un paso\n");
  scanf ("%d", &operacion);

  switch (operacion){
case 1:
    printf("El valor actual del paso es de\n");
    printf("Introduzca el nuevo valor para la medición del paso\n");
    scanf ("%f", &globalpaso);
    // Imprimir valor de globalpaso
    printf("%f", globalpaso)
  break;
default:
  break;
    }   
  }
  while (operacion != 0);
}
```

Comment: `... si tu función no recibe ningún parámetro no hace falta le pongas void ...` **incorrecto**. En C, `funcion( )` **no es lo mismo** que `funcion( void )`. En C++ es otra historia.

Comment: Yo no he dicho que sea lo mismo, lo que quiero decir es que es bastante probable que lo haya escrito por desconocimiento. Además en la práctica, la mayoría del tiempo, el comportamiento de las dos variantes es equivalente.

Comment: Pablo, gracias por la ayuda, pero continua dándome error, he cambiado lo que me dijiste y el error dice esto "main.c:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `paso'            collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" No se que podrá ser

Comment: Te he añadido el código que he probado, no entiendo muy bien que querías hacer con la función paso() así que la he quitado. Tal y como está te va a preguntar número hasta que metas un 0.

Comment: Edurex por el error de *undefined reference paso* es que no esta definida la función paso(). Que debe hacer ese método?

Comment: Vale, eso me funciona perfectamente pero lo que preguntaba era que si al cambiar la variable globalpaso, esa variable ya se quedase con ese numero introducido, y por ejemplo en un case 2 si hay un printf de globalpaso sea la añadida en el case 1 o en ausencia de esta el 65 que hay al principio

Comment: prueba a poner un printf después de `scanf ("%f", &globalpaso);`  y lo ves. La variable se quedará el último valor que le asignes.

Comment: En vez de salirme el valor me sale 0 siempre

Comment: ¿Has usado `printf("%f", globalpaso);` ? Te actualizo la pregunta para que o veas.

Comment: Me aparecia un error extraño, pero he cambiado de compilador y ya me funciona, muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Estupendo, si te ha servido marca la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: `... lo que quiero decir es que es bastante probable que lo haya escrito por desconocimiento.`. Esa frase demuestra justo lo contrario ... que no tienes claro la diferencia entre `funcion( void )` y `funcion( )` Y lo correcto es **indicar `void`** para que el compilador nos ayude a detectar nuestros errores :-)